# CSS: header, footer, and streatchable main content area

Tags: html, css, layout, stretch, stretching

I would like to have a web page with a header 120px tall, a footer 120px tall,
and a main content whose minimum height is 600px but when the browser is then
stretched vertically past 840px in height (or the user zooms out with
"control minus" on Firefox), I want the body to stretch vertically
to fill all available space minus the header and footer space.

Here is what I tried:

```
<header>This is the header.</header>
<div id="mainContent">This is the main content.</div>
<footer>This is the footer.</footer>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
header { height: 120px; background: red; }
div#mainContent { min-height: 600px; height: 100%; background: green; }
footer { height: 120px; background: blue; }
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
header { height: 120px; background: red; }
div#mainContent { height: 100%; background: green; }
footer { height: 120px; background: blue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>This is the header.</header>
<div id="mainContent">This is the main content.</div>
<footer>This is the footer.</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the correct way of achieving the effect I'm after.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the body size to a percentage you cant have a px size and percentage they don't work together.

```
div#mainContent { height: 100%; background: green; }
```

Comment: I've tried your solution. See the code above. One could think a height of 100% would expand to fill all available space in the viewport pushing the footer to the bottom but it does not. This doesn't work. Please post the correct fix.

Comment: Since nobody has answered this question, does this mean there is no way to stretch an HTML page vertically by stretching the main content area, so that if the height of the page is too small, then this height is stretched to fill the entire viewport? Is there no way to get the viewport height and thus manipulate the DOM to fill the available space, not even using jQuery?